# What is a better synonym that can replace the word lazy?

Tags: single-word-requests

Muscle atrophy mostly takes place in people that tend to be lazy.

Comment: -1: Muscle atrophy is most commonly experienced when persons suffer temporary disabling circumstances such as being restricted in movement and/or confined to bed as when hospitalized.

Comment: Did you look it up in a thesaurus?

Comment: Muscle atrophy takes place mainly in inactive people.

Comment: I, too, would say *inactive*. Although the answer *sendentary* isn't wrong, I believe it's less common.

Answer (score 2):

**Sedentary**, or characterized by inactivity and little physical exercise, is a synonym for "lazy" with less of a judgmental connotation. It would be appropriate for an objective medical comment describing muscle atrophy.

> **Sedentary** behavior often leads to muscle atrophy.
>
> Muscle atrophy typically occurs in **sedentary** individuals.